BUILD FAILED in Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX3191 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Invalid depfile: E:\github_flutterproject\volunteer_management\.dart_tool\flutter_build\22d42863326b94f469095d8762860ae7\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: E:\github_flutterproject\volunteer_management\.dart_tool\flutter_build\22d42863326b94f469095d8762860ae7\kernel_snapshot.d
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ajs_interop; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:732:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:870:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:676:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:102:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
\> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter_3.16.3\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
\> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
\> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
\> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Here

